# How to log INFO logs in settings.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-logging

I'm trying to log some info messages specifically in django settings.py. I'm following the first example in the django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/logging/) that shows a simple configuration. The only thing I changed was having the log show INFO level messages. When I run `python manage.py runserver`, the log statement is never shown. The logs are only shown for WARNING level or above (more critical).

Here is my configuration that is located in settings.py

```
import logging
...
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True
    },
}
...
def do_something():
    logger.info('Doing Something')
do_something()
```

**Note** I'm trying to log statements only in my settings.py file as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try Placing a `level` key inside the handler

```py
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
```

I just tested this on my Local Dev, My Logger looks like this [Chopped]: (Hopefully this helps!)

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    }
}

def do():
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger('django')
    logger.info('TEST')
```

Comment: Hi Nealiu, I tested your solution and it didn't work for me. Can you please share the exact code that works for you (or some minimal version)? I am using Django 4.1.4.